# Is there a dynamic public class instance properties editor in windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

Say I have a `public class Message { public string data{ get; set; } }` and some other similar classes. Instances of classes are casted to object and stored into List. I wonder if there is a .net Windows Forms component that would allow to edit all public class properties in unified manner inspecting class automatically and supporting nested classes. Is there such component in WinForms for .net?

Answer (score 2):

[System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Give it a try and see.